# Mac Os X - last modified date is 0

Tags: java, macos, date

I'm writing a little app that returns the last modified date from a file of OSX (Yosemite).

I used the `File` (`java.io`) class, but the method `lastModified()` always return the number `0`. Below is the code I've wrote:

```
Date date = new Date();
date.setTime(file.lastModified());
```

If I print the date will be Wed Dec 31 21:00:00 BRT 1969, because `file.lastModified()` is `0`.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: does the file exist ? what does  `file.exists()` say ?

Comment: Have you tried [`Files#getLastModifiedTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getLastModifiedTime(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) from the nio2 API?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `java.nio.file.attribute`, it should do everything you need:

### java.nio.file.attribute.File:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;

class FileLastModified {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String path = "/path/to/file";

        Path file = Paths.get(path);
        FileTime time = Files.getLastModifiedTime(file);
        System.out.println("lastModifiedTime = " + time);
    }
}
```

### java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes:

Using `BasicFileAttributes` would allow you to get additional file attributes as well:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

class FileAttributes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String path = "/path/to/file";

        Path file = Paths.get(path);
        BasicFileAttributes attr =
          Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        System.out.println("lastModifiedTime = " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
        System.out.println("lastAccessTime   = " + attr.lastAccessTime());
    }
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html

### java.io.File:

If you wanted to stick with `java.io.File` you could use something like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class timeStamp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String start = getTimeStamp();
        System.out.println(start);
    }

    public static String getTimeStamp() {
        File file = new File(fileTime());
        long lastModifytime = file.lastModified();
        Date date = new Date(lastModifytime);
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
        return df.format(date);
    }

    private static String fileTime() {
        String fileTime = "/path/to/file"; 
        return fileTime;
    }
}
```

I prefer `java.nio.file.attribute` over `java.io.file` because it has the capabilities built right in, which equates to writing less code and likely less things to go wrong.

Comment: Could you explain why this approach would work when the other isn't working?

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Something is obviously missing from the code that lastModified is relying on (most likely the correct path to the file). If the code were to check a file that didn't exist then it would usually come back with the date `Dec 31, 1969 5:00:00 PM`, although without seeing more of the OPs code it's hard to say exactly why the other one is not working properly.

Comment: What is up with that second block of code? You have an empty unused class, `true` as an `if` condition, and an if statement with no body. It's not good code.

Comment: Instead of reading the attribute, you can use [Files.getLastModifiedTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getLastModifiedTime-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-) which does essentially the same thing.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: I was in a hurry, and the code was taken from another project. I only added it to show the basic concepts of `lastModified()`, which was probably a mistake. Anyway, it should be a bit cleaned it up now...

Comment: @VGR: Is that a suggestion or a comment? I'm not sure there's any advantage of using `getLastModifiedTime` over `readAttributes`. I used `readAttributes` because it's versatile, and can be used for more than just getting the last modified time.

Comment: If you need other attributes, then sure, `readAttribtes` is appropriate.  If you only need the modification time, as the question seems to indicate, I'd favor `Files.getLastModifiedTime`.

Comment: @VGR: Can you explain why though, what's the advantage?

Comment: The only advantage is readability.  And perhaps fewer import statements.